# how to get event of change in enum value?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have created 1 enum
when I use it as a property for a custom control, I want to fire a event for change of the enum property.Please Help.

Comment: What do you believe to be enum-specific here? Do you know how to handle changes to non-enum properties? Have you tried using the same approach for an enum property?

Comment: I have created a square control. It has enum as a property.The enum is declared in App.xaml.cs and I want to get an event when the enum property of that particular instance changes.

Comment: That didn't actually answer any of my questions...

Comment: Please bear my questions in mind for the next time you have a problem - work out whether what you want to ask is *really* as specific as you're making it out to be. (Note that there's nothing within the accepted answer which is enum-specific.)

Comment: okay! I'll make sure to be more specific while asking qstn.thnx fr guiding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the setter to call a function or to call an event delegate.

```
  public enum PersonName
  {
      Eric,
      George,
      David,
      Frank
  }

  private PersonName myPersonName

  public PersonName MyPersonName
  {
      get { return myPersonName; }
      set
      {
          myPersonName = value;
          //simply call what you want done
          PersonNamePropertyChanged();
      }
  }
```

See more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx
which is done using the INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 5):

A **psudocode**

define your delegate

```
public void delegate EnumPropertyChangedDelegate(object sender, Enum newValue);
```

define event

```
public event EnumPropertyChangedDelegate  EnumPropertyChanged;
```

and in your property

```
private MyEnum myEnum = .... some value
public MyEnum EnumProperty
{
     get {return myEnum;} 

     set {
         if(value != myEnum)
         {
             myEnum = value;
             if(EnumPropertyChanged!=null)
                 EnumPropertyChanged(this, myEnum);
         }
     }   


}
```

Comment: @chirag: in the class where you have a property. So the consumer of that class have to subscribe to the event and recieve notification as soon as someone changes that property.